# Initial direction of intersection between two moving vehicles?

Tags: mathematics, projectile-physics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Predicting enemy position in order to have an object lead its target](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4995/predicting-enemy-position-in-order-to-have-an-object-lead-its-target)

I'm working with a bit of projectile prediction for my AI and I'm looking for some ideas, any input?

If a blue vehicle is moving in a direction at a constant speed of **X** m/s and a stationary orange vehicle has a rocket that travels **Y** m/s, which initial direction would the orange vehicle have to fire the rocket for it to hit the blue vehicle at the earliest time in the future?

[image: Initial direction of intersection]

Thanks for reading!

Comment: You certainly have the artistic skill for it, but I would suggest putting your answer on one of the other questions. We try to keep duplicates to a minimum, and adding answers to a duplicate diminishes those efforts. But do as you wish, I'm just one guy with an opinion. BTW, Odonata looks good, can't wait to play.