# Leading a target with edge casting

Tags: game-mechanics, linear-algebra, movement-prediction, aiming

I am trying to write a movement prediction code. I have found the quadratic method with these topics:

- [1]: [How to calculate shot angle and velocity to hit a moving target?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25277/how-to-calculate-shot-angle-and-velocity-to-hit-a-moving-target)
- [2]: http://howlingmoonsoftware.com/wordpress/leading-a-target/

I have implemented this without problems. The problem is how can I add enemy hitbox calculation (I want to fire at edge of enemy for precision)

```
local cos = targetDirection:dot(toTargetDirection)
local absCos = math.abs(cos)

local sin = math.sqrt(1 - (cos * cos))
local absSin = math.abs(sin)

local cot = cos / sin

local absCot = math.abs(cot)
local delta = 1 - ((cos * cos) + (sin * sin))

local position = targetPosition + targetVelocity * delay
position = position + targetVelocity * network.latency

position = position - toTargetDirection * (target.boundingRadius + width)
position = position - targetDirection * (target.boundingRadius + width)

position = position - toTargetDirection * (absSin * (target.boundingRadius + 
width))
position = position - targetDirection * (absCos * (target.boundingRadius + 
width))

local toPosition = position - sourcePosition
local toPositionDirection = toPosition:norm()
local spellVelocity = toPositionDirection * speed

local a = targetVelocity:dot(targetVelocity) - 
spellVelocity:dot(spellVelocity)
local b = targetVelocity:dot(toPosition) * 2
local c = toTarget:dot(toPosition)

local discriminant = b * b - 4 * a * c

if (discriminant < 0) then
   return
end

local time = 2 * c / (math.sqrt(discriminant) - b)
```

So far tried this but it's still not casting edge with precision.

Comment: Looks like nobody is know the solution :(

Comment: Two possibilities: 1) Nobody knows how to do hitbox calculation (unlikely) 2) Nobody has a clear idea *what kind of help you need* with hitbox calculation. So, try editing your question to explain in detail what you've tried so far and where you're stuck, or how the results you're getting differ from what you want. Editing to add detail attracts more attention to questions, and makes it easier to write high-quality answers.

Comment: Updated. I want to cast edge because i want to increase hitchance in low range.

Comment: Can you walk us through (or even diagram) an example of how casting an edge gives better hit chance than the alternative you have in mind?

Comment: In mid-short range target can't dodge with backward/inverse movement. It depends on speed.

Comment: Don't just tell us the conclusion: edit your question to walk us through the steps of *how* a non-edge-casting technique leads to inaccuracy or dodging at the right range/speed, and *how* your proposed "edge casting" technique corrects for that.

Comment: Basicly it shortens impact/intersect time. If i try to cast target's center lets say 1.1 sec futher of target. If i try to cast behind/edge of target i should cast 0.9 second. Smaller Impact Time = Smaller dodge reaction